# powershell method on a null-valued expression

Tags: powershell

I have a script thats been running fine for months but over the last few days when I run it I'm getting this error - any help in debugging it?

here's line 66 in the code:

```
$remotefilehash =  ($remoteFiles | Where-Object { -not ($_ | Select-String -Quiet -NotMatch -Pattern '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )') } -replace '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )', '$0=  ' -join "`n") | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

I wonder if for some reason $remoteFiles is zero ? ie null and hence throws this error?

```
Where-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'replace'.
At P:\scripts\code\pcloud_sync.ps1:66 char:125
+ ... ing -Quiet -NotMatch -Pattern '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )') } -replace '^[a-f0 ...
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At P:\scripts\code\pcloud_sync.ps1:74 char:1
+ $diffmd5 = $remotefilehash.GetEnumerator().Where({ -not $localHashSet ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

UPDATE2

after adding the parthensis now getting another new error on the same line:

```
ConvertFrom-StringData : Data item 'a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707e' in line 'a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707e  =  My
Pictures/Tony/Automatic Upload/Tony’s iPhone/2022-10-08 21-46-21 (2).mov' is already defined.
At P:\scripts\code\pcloud_sync.ps1:66 char:179
+ ... ace '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )', '$0=  ' -join "`n") | ConvertFrom-StringData
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [ConvertFrom-StringData], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromStringDataCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At P:\scripts\code\pcloud_sync.ps1:74 char:1
+ $diffmd5 = $remotefilehash.GetEnumerator().Where({ -not $localHashSet ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: Ignore the second error, it's the first one that contains the clue to your problem :)

Comment: You need to wrap the statement with parentheses, otherwise powershell thinks `-replace` is an argument for `Where-Object`! `(($remoteFiles | Where-Object { ..... }) -replace ...`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon can you clarify the full line ?

Comment: @Tony ```$remotefilehash =  (($remoteFiles | Where-Object { -not ($_ | Select-String -Quiet -NotMatch -Pattern '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )') }) -replace '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )', '$0=  ' -join "`n") | ConvertFrom-StringData```

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen added a second update to the original post

Comment: Sounds like you have duplicate keys in the input :) Show us the source file(s) if you need more help

Comment: hmm but in a later step I put them all in a hash set - IDK why its complaining about it here